# Swift Firebase UICollectionView - Image thumbnails inconsistent

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView to display images downloaded from firebase. The problem is that the download thumbnail is very inconsistent. Sometimes it loads correctly but most of the time the thumbnails are duplicated or in the wrong cell.

**Firebase Download**

```
func downloadImages(refreshing: Bool, refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?) {
        self.posts.removeAll()
        self.collectionViews.reloadData()
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                self.posts = []
                for item in dict {
                    let json = JSON(item.value)
                    let uid = json["uid"].stringValue
                    var name: String = json["businessName"].stringValue
                    let address: String = json["businessStreet"].stringValue
                    let state: String = json["businessCity"].stringValue
                    let caption: String = json["caption"].stringValue
                    let downloadURL: String = json["download_url"].stringValue
                    let timestamp = json["timestamp"].doubleValue
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)
                    let postID: String = json["postID"].stringValue

                    let lat = json["businessLatitude"].doubleValue
                    let long = json["businessLongitude"].doubleValue
                    let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

                    let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                    let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                    let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                    let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)
                    //let distanceLabelText = "Not Available"

                    let usersReference = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: uid)
                    usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                            let userInfo = dict.allValues[0]
                            let userJSON = JSON(userInfo)
                            name = userJSON["name"].stringValue

                        }
                        let post = Post(uid: uid, caption: caption, downloadURL: downloadURL, name: name, date: date, address: address, state: state, distance: distanceLabelText, postID: postID)
                        self.collectionViews.reloadData()
                        self.posts.append(post)
                        self.posts.sort {$0.distance.compare($1.distance) == .orderedAscending}
                        //self.collectionViews.reloadData()


                    })
                }
            }
            if refreshing {
                self.posts.removeAll()
                self.collectionViews.reloadData()
                refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            }
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
        })

    }
```

**UICollectionView Cell**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.postImage.image = nil
        cell.postImage.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
        if self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL != nil {
            cell.postImage.downloadImagezzz(from: self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL)
        } else {
            print("\n \(indexPath.row) could not return a value for pathToImage256 from Post. \n")
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**Download and set image**

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImagezzz(from imgURL: String) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, responds, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I think the problem is the last part titled "Download and set image".

Comment: Does it become inconsistent after you scroll collectionView? I don't know why you use `sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad` but not use `SDWebImage`'s download image method.

Comment: It's inconsistent on the first load and refreshing. The "sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad" was from some else trying to help

Comment: You think using the SDWebImage download method would change this?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it should change this. Something like `cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL), placeholderImage: nil)`.

Comment: That code doesn't work

Comment: So I have no idea now :)

Comment: thanks for giving it a try

Comment: That code throws a error "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: I guess that you should fix it yourself. My typo. `cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL), placeholderImage: nil)`

Comment: Hey it seems that did it! it works so far so good! Do you want to add a answer for points?

Comment: Great!!! Did it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange when you use `sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad` method but don't use `SDWebImage`'s download image method.

Use below method instead of `downloadImagezzz` will fix the problem

```
cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.posts[indexPath.row].downloadURL), placeholderImage: nil)
```